# How to delete free space in Disc Managment - Windows

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I just tried to install `Ubuntu` in my laptop but failed. So, i searched the web and delete a volume that `Ubuntu` installed in in `Disc Management`. But when I deleted the volume, it turn into a 'free space' which contains 137.51GB space(My hard disc got 250GB). When I open `Computer`, I saw that my computer's hard disc had decrease until 87.7GB. I tried to delete `Free Space` in `Disc Managment` but failed.

Comment: It sounds like you're really asking how to make your Windows drive use the 137.51 GB that's 'free space'.  You may be able to right click on the Windows drive in Disk Manangement, and select extend volume.  If not, you'll likely need to look for a partition extending tool.

Comment: You need to extend an existing partition. You cannot delete `Free Space`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Windows partition was using ~100 GB and your ubuntu partition was using ~150GB. You deleted the ubuntu partition and now you have 150GB of free space plus your Windows partition.

There's nothing to delete in the free space: it's free, empty, void, unoccupied, vacant. It is an uninhabited space of nothingness.

If you want the Windows partition to be larger to use the newly available space, [extend it](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/shrink-extend-volumes-partitions-windows-7/).

[image]

If for some reason Disk Management doesn't work, you can used a third party tool like [EaseUS Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm). It has never failed me, and it uses fancy sliders that allow you to visually extend partitions and move them around.

Comment: No, `Extend Volume...` button had been disabled...

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/R6Ig0vm.png

Comment: @user2718549 You'll have to use a third party tool. Windows has locked your C: drive and the only way to extend it is from outside the OS. The program I recommended at the end of my post works nicely for me.